# how to open Nokia map app through html url

Tags: maps, here-api

how to open Nokia map app  through html url

like for iphone i use

```
 <a href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San Francisco, CA&saddr=cupertino">iphoneFind Us</a>
```

and for android  i use

```
<a href="geo:894%20Granville%20Street%20Vancouver%20BC%20V6Z%201K3">Android Find Us</a>
```

how to use for nokia

thanks in advance

Comment: With Nokia you mean what? S40, Symbian, Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

For a web page, try something like this : [HERE](http://here.com/whereis/Invalidenstra%C3%9Fe,%20117,%20Berlin,%2010117,%20Germany)

```
<a href="http://here.com/whereis/Invalidenstraße, 117, Berlin, 10117, Germany">HERE Maps</a>
```

But for Windows Phones, also look into the [HERE Maps Launchers API](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html), specifically the section on URI schemes.